# Why isn't Social.ReportScore working in this script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, google-play-services, google-play-games

I've made this simple script to post a score to the Google Play Leaderboards. I know I typed the Leaderboard code right because it shows the name of the leaderboard. However, instead of showing the score of 54321, it says "Be the first to upload a score!". What is wrong with this script? I've spent hours looking online but it seems I did everything right! THANK YOU

```
using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 using GooglePlayGames;
 using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;

 public class PlayGames: MonoBehaviour {

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () 
{
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
    //PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate; not working get error CS0201: 
    //Only assignment, call, inrement, decrement, and new oject expressions can be used as a statement.
    //so I'm trying to get this to work with a bool
    PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate((bool success) => {
        //hope this works!
    });
    if (!PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.localUser.authenticated)
    {
        return;
    }
    PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ReportScore(543210,"Cgglqe3m-mcQAhAI", (bool success) =>
        {
            if (success)
            {
                Social.ShowLeaderboardUI();
                Debug.Log("log to leaderboard succeeded");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("log to leaderboard failed");
            }
        });

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the log at some point when debuging on a device? 
Take in consideration that ReportScore is an async call

just to be sure, try this code:

```
Social.ReportScore (54321, "Cgglqe3m-mcQAhAI", 
  success => 
{
   Social.ShowLeaderboardUI ();
});
```

**EDIT:**

This is what is working for me: 
Call `PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();` once in your code.
After that, call `PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate`. 
When i want to log a score, i use this:

```
    public static void LogScoreInGameService(int score, string leaderBoard)
    {
        if (!PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.localUser.authenticated)
        {
            return;
        }
        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ReportScore(score, leaderBoard, (bool success) =>
        {
            if (success)
            {
                Debug.Log("log to leaderboard succeeded");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("log to leaderboard failed");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I tried your script, and same thing. The first time I open the leaderboard scene, it logs me in. The second time it opens the leaderboard but asks me to be the 1st person to post a score. How do I see the debug log from a device? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks again for your help, however it still isn't posting the score with the new script I made (shown in my question). What can possibly be wrong?

Comment: i suggest you to first check that you configured everythings right. From your question i see that you use Unity, you should add the resources from the develloper console to Unity. you should also check in the developer console that your leaderboard is available, and that it can receive int as a valid value. After that, add logs to your code to see where you fail. anyway, be sure to follow the instructions here: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity ,this is the git repo of the google play service (or you can search on google)

Comment: Did you find your problem ?

Comment: I fixed it by resetting absolutely everything that could be reset. So I loaded a new .APK, created new leaderboards, new keystore etc... seems to work fine now!